# set regex for Firebase reset password

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

I'm currently building an app for android using firebase and I faced a problem.

I forced to make a strong password when a user creates its account, however, if the user wants to reset the password the Firebase will send him the link which redirects him to this page:
[image: firebase reset password page]
On this page the user can create a new password, and, he can basically type 123456 and it will work.

My question is- Can I make a validation for this input in firebase?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it is not possible to validate it through firebase. So what I did is implemented my own reset password page with the help of firebase dynamic links

Comment: I have the same issue. If you can give more information about how you implemented the solution, it would be great.